# Spring Security with AngularJS Login 401 Unauthorized

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to successfully authenticate a user with Spring Security using AngularJS on the front end.

Basically what is supposed to happen is: 
1) A new user should be able to fill out the registration form with a unique username and password 
2) Upon submit, Angular POSTs the user/pass combination to the URL specified by spring security.
3) Spring Security verifies the account and logs the user in.
4) The user's session begins and is shown as logged in on the front end.

The hangup is occurring in step 2. **The information is not successfully posted to the spring login URL.** My failure handler is tripped (in the code below) and the login process is halted.

```
POST http://localhost:8080/libroomreserve/login 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Here is my Spring Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationFailure authFailure;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationSuccess authSuccess;

@Autowired
private EntryPointUnauthorizedHandler unauthorizedHandler;

@Autowired
private UserDetailServiceImpl userDetails;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .successHandler(authSuccess) //sets status to 200 OK
                .failureHandler(authFailure) //sets status to 401 Unauthorized
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                    .permitAll();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetails);
}
```

Failure Handler:

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFailure extends    SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler{

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
  }
}
```

Success Handler:

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationSuccess extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler{

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
  }
}
```

AuthenticationEntryPoint:

```
@Component
public class EntryPointUnauthorizedHandler implements AuthenticationEntryPoint{

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest hsr, HttpServletResponse hsr1, AuthenticationException ae) throws IOException, ServletException {
    hsr1.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Access Denied.");
    }  
}
```

On the AngularJS side, this is my service:

```
.factory('sessionService', function($http, $base64){
    var session = {};
    session.login = function(data){
        return $http.post("/libroomreserve/login", "username=" + data.userName + "&password" + data.password,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            })
            //.then() is a "PROMISE" which is executed after initial return function is performed        
            .then(function(){
                console.log("Logged in the user!");
                localStorage.setItem("session", {}); 
            }, function(){
                console.log("Error logging in the user...");
            });
    };
    session.logout = function(){
        localStorage.removeItem("session");
        console.log("User has been logged out.");
    };
    session.isLoggedIn = function(){
        return localStorage.getItem("session") !== null;
    };
    return session;
})
```

For reference, I am following the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fx7hoza7wIA) by Chris Henkel. I can't find any discrepancies between his code and mine.

As an aside, the newly-registered user is being logged into the database so the credentials are available for authentication.